# How to display NaNs (in a pandas df Float Column) as empty cells?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
dtypes: float64(1)
     VAR_A
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    13.0
3    4.0
4    9.0
```

When I try to replace NaN with blank/whitespace as either:

```
tgt['VAR_A_NEW'] = pd.to_numeric(tgt['VAR_A'].replace(np.nan, '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
tgt['VAR_A_NEW'] = tgt['VAR_A'].fillna('')

print(tgt.info(verbose=True))
print(tgt.head())
```

I get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Data columns (total 2 columns):
VAR_A          63 non-null float64
VAR_A_NEW      74 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
   VAR_A    VAR_A_NEW
0  NaN  
1  0.0      0
2  13.0     13
3  4.0      4
4  9.0      9
```

Clearly, the variable attribute has changed from float to object. I understand it doesn't make sense conceptually to have a float column with blankspace ('') value.

**Is there any way to display the NaN values of the float var as blank/empty cells using the**

```
1) print(head()) statement    
2) pd.to_csv statement
```

Comment: So which number is an empty string equal to? ))

Comment: Right, I know conceptually it makes no sense to do this. I am just asking to see if there is a way to force this behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Well if you want to have both numbers and strings in a column then it's going to have object data type. Maybe you just want NaNs to be displayed as empty cells?

Comment: Right, I want the NaNs to be displayed as empty cells for the float variable.

Comment: `''` is not a numeric value, so **no**, you can't keep the column as `float` **and** store `''`. The object column could hold both types, but really you shouldn't. You'll only have headaches trying to do any operations in the future.

Comment: Then I think it's best to edit the question accordingly and specify how you are displaying the dataframe.

Comment: Changed the question and added more color to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the style method to replace nan in your dataframe view.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21527

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

from IPython.core.display import HTML 
HTML(df.style.render().replace('nan',''))
```

`df.to_csv()` defaults to storing nan as ''.  You can replace it by passing an argument to the na_rep parameter. `df.to_csv(na_rep='missing')`